# Reload changed classes in IntelliJ groovy console

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, groovy-console

Is it possible to reload changed classes when in IntelliJ's groovy console?
I've seen there's a command for doing so in groovysh, but it seems groovysh is not the same as IntelliJ's groovy console.

Answer (score 1):

See here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reloading-classes.html

From the site: 
To reload changed classes

Do one of the following:
On the main menu, choose Run | Reload Changed Classes.
On the main menu, choose Build | Compile "class_name" to recompile an altered class during debug.
Select
In the Reload Changed Classes dialog box, confirm reloading. Results are displayed in the Messages tool window.
To configure reloading behavior

On the main menu, choose File | Settings , and then expand the Debugger node.
Open HotSwap page.
Click one of the radio buttons in the group Reload classes after compilation. You can opt to always reload classes, reload after confirmation, or never do it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  However, I'm running code in the console without being in debugging mode.  I'd prefer to be able to do this outside of debugging.

Comment: hmm.. not sure if you can in that case. Are you using grails or any other framework?

Comment: Then I don't think you can

Answer (score 1):

In IDEA 15.0.3 I can use this workflow:

- Ctrl-Shift-F9 (Compile)
- Ctrl-F2 (stop Groovy)
- Ctrl-Enter (rerun Groovy script)